# What is the meaning of "Temes sentir más de la cuenta"?

Tags: significado

I'm finding several different translations on this. It would be great if a native Spanish speaker can settle this for me.

The translations I've found:

> *Temes sentir más de la cuenta*:
>
> Let me feel a few too many times.
>
> You're reluctant to feel one too many.
>
> let me feel more obligated

Comment: I'd say it means "You are afraid of feeling too much or feeling past over your limit"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*más de la cuenta* means that it's more than should've been given.

Relate *cuenta* (noun) to *contar* (verb).
It's a common idiom:

> 1. *Traje más regalos de la cuenta.* (= I brought more presents than I expected to bring.)
> 2. *Tomé más de la cuenta.* (= I drank and I exceeded the alcohol intake.)
> 3. *Se pasó de la cuenta.* (= He/She made something bad that was out of the bounds.)
> 4. *Te va a pasar la cuenta si sigues fumando.* (= you're going to die.)
> 5. *Le pasó la cuenta cargar tantos sacos.* (= the person got injured.)

Comment: Hmm. So "temes sentir mas de la cuenta" would translate to "you're afraid to feel 'too much'. Given the context of the song from which the phrase taken ('Eres para mi [Julieta Venegas]), I interpret 'too much' to be hyperbole. Thanks Ustanak, you've relieved my frustration of not understanding this. Now I can go to sleep. Hahaa!

Comment: @RockAnthonyJohnson you can look for the meaning of some expressions in the DRAE. This one [happens to be there](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BaAYElz) along with the various expressions that can be formed with _cuenta_. According to the DRAE, "más/menos de la cuenta" means _más/menos de lo debido o de lo conveniente_. This is just to confirm what Ustanak said in his answer.

Comment: I'm always amazed at the differences between the several Spanish languages spoken along the world. Your two last examples sound better to me using _factura_: _Te va a pasar factura si sigues fumando_, _le pasó factura cargar tantos sacos_. Also note that _más de la cuenta_, _pasarse de la cuenta_ y _pasar la cuenta_ are different expressions. You should note that in the answer, as the second example should be _tomé más de la cuenta_ to use the same expression. Same with _estás fumando más de la cuenta_ or _cargó más sacos de la cuenta_.

Comment: @RockAnthonyJohnson The usual translation for _más de la cuenta_ would be indeed _too much_ but here the meaning is "more than you'd like".

Comment: For me the second and third sentences are something different. In those cases I would have said "tomé más de la cuenta", but for the third I wouldn't know. For me the third sounds like he/she went out of the budget.

Comment: I edited the second example to make it fit with the usage. I slipped my mind when I wrote it.

Answer (score 1):

Temes sentir más de la cuenta se traduce literalmente a You're afraid of feeling too much. It is probably used in a relationship context, like You're afraid of getting too attached.